how to run a service with a progress screen on top of main application screen in Kotlin
I need to run a Splash screen or Progress Bar Screen while the Main Application Loads.
And when ever the Main Application changes of screen show the Progress Bar Screen while it loads.
I looked around and found that I can not have two UI threads in the Kotlin Application so maybe I can call a service to run a parallel UI Thread. The regular Splash Screen does not suffice because is use only at the start of the application.  Also found the Application can call own services but they appear to be background jobs only not a top Screen.
I do not need the user to interact with the Splash/Progress Screen only to appear at the top and close when the Main Screen finish loading.
Can you direct me to a code sample application with that or similar feature?

The idea of a splashscreen is to bridge the time that your app needs to load, so it only works up until the app is loaded (the splashscreen has no program code, only a configuration so it can be run by the Android system). Anything after that must be handled by your app code.
You are right that there is only one UI thread, but you are wrong assuming that that poses a problem. The soluion is not to try some trickery with additional processes, the solution is to properly use the single UI thread as it is.
Whenever your UI needs to wait for some data to be loaded, don't block the UI thread until the data is available, just suspend and launch a new coroutine on the main thread that displays the desired progress bar. When you use Compose it can be as simple as having a State object that you can use to differentiate the cases where you are still waiting for data (e.g. Loading) and when the data is loaded (e.g. Success). Then display a CircularProgressIndicator() (or whatever you want) for Loading and your regular screen for Success.
The key here is to make sure all your code is main-safe, then you can easily run multiple things concurrently on the single UI thread.

Leviathan, thank you for your answer. Can I add my screen code and you help me identify where I can add withContext statements to make it main-safe. The screen has a modal bottom sheet that I have functions that can be change to incorporate the statement but that bottomsheet is supposed not  to execute when the Screen loads as it is inside a "false if statement". The initial code only have @Composable functions. I really can't see where the code is being blocked.

Yes, just ask a new question which focuses on your specific code asking how you can fix the undesired behavior (like ANRs or missing progress indicators). Make sure to provide a [mre], that is, your code should be as short as possible while still being executible so we can reproduce the issue.

Giving an executable code is really difficult as  the screen purpose is to enter data to a ROOM database with a ViewModel and handled with a Navigation Controller. Also modal bottom sheet has many Composables that are DropDownMenus that are populated with internal JSON data.

I have created a new project in Android Studio with bare minimum code. How do I create a reprex for the Android project? The reprex package is for R code not Kotlin.

What is a "reprex package" and what has that to do with this answer?

When you go to the minimal reproducible example link has another link to that package as a way to create the MRE. But anyway how can I upload the project or share it?

I added this new Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78967489/either-launcheffect-or-async-coroutine-in-kotlin-is-being-aborted-which-and-why with an attempt of a MRE.

Is there anything else regarding this answer, or does it sufficiently answer your initial question?

I am still struggling to make the code main-safe. Found a way to make Progress Bar while loading other screen and runs a bit better but still it is "janking" and the other screen is slow to load. I change most of the blocking code to launch/join or async/await but the join(s) and await(s) are blocking. Also have problems with the join/await aborting and do not know why.  I am confused about LaunchedEffect and  Coroutines, I will post a new Question about that.

You don't need join or await, just update your state at the end of your blocking code. The usual way to go is to return a flow which emits the data as a flow.

In my case I need to wait for the results because they are lists that  otherwise generate runtime errors or show bad or misleading content to the user.

Thank you for your help. Is not the answer I was looking for but help me reach a closer to the solution.
